# Can I save email attachments directly to SkyDrive?

Tags: onedrive, outlook.com

How can I save email attachments in Hotmail directly to my SkyDrive without first downloading them to my computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, unless it is for e-mail attachments you are sending.

From a Microsoft rep directly (via [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aetqOygWAqD0J%3aanswers.microsoft.com/message/3e410427-c085-40fe-a086-151255338e4e?threadId=5c9c0fa6-cd5e-4bc0-941a-72495eed6f7d%20) forum which is available now only due to Google cache):

> there is a feature in Hotmail that allows the attachments that you’ll
>   be sending, to be saved directly to your SkyDrive account. To enable
>   this feature, please refer to the steps below:   Sign in to your
>   Hotmail account and go to your inbox. Click on Options located under
>   your profile name, choose More options. Under Writing email, click on
>   Attachments. Choose the option Always send files using SkyDrive. Click
>   Save button.
>
> This feature is only for the attachment that you, as the sender, will
>   attach. **There is no option that will directly save the attachment you
>   *received* in your account, to your SkyDrive.** For this case, you really
>   have to download the attachment first and then manually upload it to
>   your SkyDrive account.

Comment: well that's a bummer

Comment: If that forum were still open, I would say you should pile on.  ...but maybe MS is listening anyway.  :)  (Are you hearing this, Bing?)

Comment: "via this forum which is available now only due to Google cache" "If that forum were still open" - What in blazes are you on about? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-files/how-do-you-save-an-email-attachment-from-hotmail/5c9c0fa6-cd5e-4bc0-941a-72495eed6f7d?msgId=3e410427-c085-40fe-a086-151255338e4e

Comment: The link I had for that site would not work.  Only going to the Google cache did.  That's just the way it happened.

Comment: ...nice to know the spot is there for the OP to voice his concern, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) (If This Then That) to do this. Create a filter in Hotmail which forwards mail with attachments or manually forward attachments to trigger@recipe.ifttt.com. Then use [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/68166) and connect to your Hotmail and Skydrive account.

Answer (score 0):

You can save attachments from Hotmail to the SkyDrive without having to download them.

The steps to follow are

- Open the email in Hotmail and click the "View online" link
- The document will open in the appropriate Office Web App viewer. Click the "Edit in Browser" link
- The document will automatically be saved in your "My Documents" folder on SkyDrive

That is it your document has been saved on SkyDrive without you downloading the file locally.

Comment: What if the attachment isn't a file format that the viewer recognizes?

Comment: That will only work if it is an editable document and will not work with images, PDF's etc.